# how to override a method when I have a "thunk"

Tags: scala

I have a thunk that take no parameter and return a List of case class(WhitelistRule), and a getWhitelist method that return a List of case class(WhitelistRule), how to override getWhitelist in main class?

```
trait AuthorizedServices {
  def getWhitelist: List[WhitelistRule]
}

  case class WhitelistRule(accountId: String, ruleName: String)

  type WhitelistRuleThunk = () => List[WhitelistRule]

class AuthorizedServicesImpl(Whitelist : => Map[String, WhitelistRuleThunk])
    extends AuthorizedServices {

    override def getWhitelist = {}

}
```

I did this but it's type mismatch, required scala.List[WhitelistRule], found scala.List[WhitelistRuleThunk].

```
override def getWhitelist = {
     Whitelist.get("string").toList
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the "thunk" to get the value. Assuming that `WhiteList.get` returns an `Option` it looks like this:

```
override def getWhitelist = {
  Whitelist.get("string").toList.flatMap(_())
}
```

---

`_()` is shorthand for `f => f()` so it is a function that calls the value that is given to it, which in this case is type `WhitelistRuleThunk`. So this calls the thunk which returns the `List[WhiteListRule]`.

The `flatMap` is required because there is a `List` of `WhitelistRuleThunk`s and each rule returns a `List[WhiteListRule]` so a simple `map` would give `List[List[WhiteListRule]]`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for reply,  what does (_()) mean, is that means call the thunk? If it is, can you explain why?

Comment: I've added some explanation, hope it helps